# why IE 11 Shows error when input html tag writes dynamically?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm developing a sample web application on mvc5(Razor) in visual studio 2013 and use IE(version 11) to run and test my project.

i have a input hidden field in my view and generate it and write it on my view.

```
 <input type="hidden" value="@myid" id="@myid">
```

generated id and value is this "c73dlFoiMsnhS7XTGwdejA==" and input finally looks like this:

```
<input type='hidden' value='c73dlFoiMsnhS7XTGwdejA==' id='c73dlFoiMsnhS7XTGwdejA=='>
```

when i dynamically write this input IE gives me this error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 37, column 59140 in http://localhost:4026
  /f70e83bc11bd432888e7370e9091f30f/browserLink

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  
input#c73dlFoiMsnhS7XTGwdejA==>div>div>div>img>div>br>div.boxpostcontentholder>
```

but when i put this tag by hard code (that i show it up in finally) IE does not show this error is it a bug in IE ?
i test this with Firefox version 25.0 and it works fine without showing errors.

Comment: Which HTML doctype are you declaring? If you are declaring it as anything other than HTML5 I am fairly sure that the equals signs are invalid content for an id attribute.

Comment: This is a problem with BrowserLink. See step 4 for how to turn it off - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx